# Impala: LIKE does not capture CONCAT output

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

Hi I'm not sure why CASE does not work when I run this on Impala.

So this query should check if at the end of account number there is exactly the same sort code as in other column in that database - but it does not do the job. The outcome of `CONCAT` is exactly as expected eg `'%18002'` but does not find the match.

```sql
SELECT

account_no

,sort_code

,CASE WHEN account_no LIKE CONCAT("'",'%',CAST(sort_code AS STRING),"'") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CHECK

,CONCAT("'",'%',CAST(sort_code AS STRING),"'") AS CONCAT_OUTPUT

FROM bddaoao01p.aml_alerts_control_flags;
```

the output of the query:

[image]

any idea what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT account_no,sort_code,
       CASE WHEN account_no LIKE CONCAT('%',CAST(sort_code AS STRING)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CHECK
       CONCAT("'",'%',CAST(sort_code AS STRING),"'") AS CONCAT_OUTPUT
FROM bddaoao01p.aml_alerts_control_flags
```